# subversion - get revision number from matching pattern

Tags: svn, revision

**Problem :**

There is some unusual commit made on this file and nobody knows who committed it and `svn log /path/of/file` gives very long list. That will consume lots of time.

**Expected result :**

So basically I'm trying to find a way to get the revision number in svn when matching pattern was committed in a file. For example, I have file called `master.cf` which has a string called `foobar`, but I want to know the revision number of that commit so that I come to know when that matching string was committed and by whom?

Is there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `svn blame`: `svn blame master.cf | grep foobar`.